# How to parse array from MySQL column in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, parsing

I have column `extra_fields` in table.

In column i have array, and I need to parse it

```
 [{"id":"1","value":"fdsds"},{"id":"2","value":"\/images\/powered_by.png"},{"id":"3","value":"fdsfdsfdsfds"},{"id":"4","value":"<p>fdsfdsfdsfds<\/p>"}]
```

Try to do it with this code,

```
$extrafields = array();
foreach($this->item->extra_fields as $item)
{   
    $extrafields[$item->id] = $item->value;
}
```

but return empty string or...I don't know what

Comment: Use json_decode ? it seems to be a JSON string.

Comment: it's return me string "Array" after json_decode

Comment: json_decode will return an array.... so if you try to echo that result, then it will output "Array"..... PHP requires you to reference array elements when you try to display them, not simply the array itself

Comment: echo with print_r($your_array), after json_decode

Comment: Thanks, but after 

`$array = $this->item->extra_fields;
$obj = json_decode($array);
print_r($obj[0]);`

i have 

`stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [value] => fdsds )`

how I can get access to "id" or "value" ?

Comment: Square brackets (`[]`) and the key for arrays; `->` for object properties: Use `$obj[0]->id` or `$obj[0]->value`

Answer (score 0):

it is unclear as to what you want to achieve but here you go:

```
$test = json_decode('[{"id":"1","value":"fdsds"},{"id":"2","value":"\/images\/powered_by.png"},{"id":"3","value":"fdsfdsfdsfds"},{"id":"4","value":"<p>fdsfdsfdsfds<\/p>"}]');

$extrafields = array();
foreach ($test as $key => $item) {
    $extrafields[$item->id] = $item->value;
}
```

Comment: Did you try Vladyslav ? Please be clever and test yourself.